# Hosting PyQt Application on Server

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, host

I have written a PyQt Application that runs on my Raspberry Pi. Now I want to take it a step further and access the Application from other devices while it is running on my Pi. The Application has to be interactable, see the images.

I imagine I would have to setup the Pi as a Server (There's tutorials on the Pi website), but how do I actually access the GUI then? It's supposed to be like a remote connection but just through a web browser without installing third party software on my device.

[image: Picture of the GUI]

Answer (score 1):

you are thinking of pyqt as a presentation layer. it is not that.
you would have to rewrite your app as a client-server app, separating the logic from the presentation.
google for "client server programming model" for some idea's
good luck